# Compute $\int \frac {dx} {(a + b \cos x)^2} $ for $a > b.$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Let $a>b$ be real numbers. As the title suggests, I would like to compute $$\int \frac 1 {(a + b \cos x)^2} \, dx.$$

My attempt consisted of converting the cosine to half-angle tangents, substituting the half-angle tangent for $t$, and simplifying to $$\int \frac{2(1+t^2)}{[(a+b)+(a-b)t^2]^2} \, dt.$$
From here, I multiplied and divided the integrand by $(a-b)$, added an $(a+b)-2b$ to the numerator, and simplified it to $$\frac{4b}{a-b}\int {\left(\frac 1 {[(a+b)+(a-b)t^2]^2} + \frac{2t}{a-b} \right)} \, dt.$$
Now, just looking at the integral left, I substituted $t$ for $\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}} \tan\theta$, did some simplifying, converted the resulting $\cos^2\!\theta$ in the numerator to $1+\cos 2 \theta$, and wrapped up the integral, finishing up with $$\frac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{a-b}-\frac{2b}{(a^2-b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\left(\arctan \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}\tan \frac{x}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt{ \frac{a+b}{a-b}}\tan 
 \frac{x}{2}}{1+{ \frac{a-b}{a+b}\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}} \right)}$$

This is apparently wrong. Can someone help me with why?

Comment: Apart from a tiny little thing, yeah, thanks! Where did I mess up with the MathJax?

Comment: There were three missing }'s. You can see what I did in Side-by-side markdown.

Comment: Sheesh. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: @Kaind see carefully it is provided that, $a \gt b$

Comment: @Kaind: can you elaborate? Yes, it doesn't work for the example you provided, but the case a=b isn't considered. Which other case renders the first step wrong?

Comment: Isn't that the point? Like, the question knows there're going to be different results based on what relation exists between a and b, so it just chose $a>b$. Yes, the result is different if the relationship between a and b was different, but why should that make it *wrong*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as follows after half-angle substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}2$

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{2(1+t^2)}{[(a+b)+(a-b)t^2]^2} \, dt\\
=& \frac2{a^2-b^2} \int \frac{a[(a-b)t^2+(a+b)]+ b[(a-b)t^2-(a+b)] }{[(a+b)+(a-b)t^2]^2} \, dt \\
=& \frac2{a^2-b^2} \int \frac{a[(a-b)+\frac{a+b}{t^2} ]+ [b[(a-b)-\frac{a+b}{t^2}]}{[(a-b)t+\frac{a+b}t]^2}dt\\
=& \frac2{a^2-b^2} \left(a \int \frac{d[(a-b)t-\frac{a+b}{t}]}{[(a-b)t-\frac{a+b}t]^2+4(a^2-b^2)}
+b\int \frac{d[(a-b)t+\frac{a+b}{t}] }{[(a-b)t +\frac{a+b}t]^2}  \, \right)\\
=& \frac{a}{(a^2-b^2)^{3/2}} \tan^{-1} \frac{(a-b)t-\frac{a+b}{t}}{2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}- \frac{2b}{a^2-b^2} 
\frac{1}{(a-b)t +\frac{a+b}t}\\
=& \frac{a}{(a^2-b^2)^{3/2}} \tan^{-1} \frac{(a-b)\tan^2\frac{x}2-(a+b)}{ 2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\tan\frac{x}2 }- \frac{2b}{a^2-b^2} 
\frac{\tan\frac{x}2}{(a-b) \tan^2\frac{x}2 +(a+b)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Let us make the substitution:

$$\sinh(x) = t\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}} \Rightarrow \mathrm{d}t = \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}\cosh(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Then the denominator of the given expression can be written as

\begin{align*}
((a+b) + (a-b)t^{2})^{2} & = (a+b)^{2}\left[1 + \left(t\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}\right)^{2}\right]^{2}\\\\
& = (a+b)^{2}(1 + \sinh^{2}(x))^{2}\\\\
& = (a+b)^{2}\cosh^{4}(x)
\end{align*}

Besides that, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
2(1 + t^{2}) & = 2\left[1 + \left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)\sinh^{2}(x)\right]\\\\
& = 2\left[1 - \frac{a+b}{a-b} + \left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)(1 + \sinh^{2}(x))\right]\\\\
& = 2\left[-\frac{2b}{a-b} + \left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)\cosh^{2}(x)\right]
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, the proposed integral can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
I & = \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}\left[-\int\left(\frac{4b}{(a^{2}-b^{2})(a+b)\cosh^{3}(x)}\right)\mathrm{d}x + \int\left(\frac{2}{(a^{2}-b^{2})\cosh(x)}\right)\mathrm{d}x\right]
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't really know much about hyperbolic trig functions, though, so this is way beyond me. And I know there might be better solutions than mine- I just wanna know where I messed up there.